# Working on a remote job / German work permit/bluecard

Tags: germany, resident-permit

I currently live in Germany, been living here for almost a year and got my bluecard some months ago. Recently I've been thinking about getting a remote job to be able to spend more time in my home country or checking if it's possible working remotely in my current job. If I'm able to work remotely in my current company I guess nothing changes, but is it possible to keep my bluecard and work permit if I apply for other company to get a full time remote job?

Comment: Where would you live?

Comment: @gerrit the idea is to keep residency in germany but being able to spend long periods of time elsewhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you’re on a German blue card, you can leave the country up until 12 consecutive months without affecting your residence status.

The fact that you got the chance to keep your job working remotely is just the luxury of working in the tech industry. That’s definitely possible. I’ve been doing it for a few months in the past due to a family emergency.

Once I read somewhere that the serious downside to this kinda situation is that your time away doesn’t count against your residency in Germany. So, if that’s true, and you’re planning toward a German PR after 21 or 33 months, you might need to stay and work in the country for your time away even after you’re having 21 or 33 slips.

On the other hand, people I know just went to Ausländerbehörde providing their salary slips, language skills certificate (in the case of 21 months applications) and simply got their PR. I’m not sure if there’s actually a background check there.

I’ll look around and provide you with few links when am sober.

---

#### Update

- Obviously, your new job must not be of a self-employment/freelancing nature. Basically, you gotta work for a fully remote company based in Germany that does your social security contributions just as your current company. Your Blue Card residence title is always dependent on a company.
- According to [§§ 19a German Residence Act](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0364), in the event of changing jobs within the first 2 years of your Blue Card issuance, it should be authorized by the foreigners' office.
- The time spent outside Germany is not credited towards any application for a settlement permit.

> ***Can I interrupt my stay in Germany during the validity period of the EU Blue Card?***
>   *"Holders of an EU Blue Card are permitted to stay in a non-EU country for up to 12 consecutive months without their residence title expiring. This provision also includes family members. However, this time spent outside Germany is not credited towards any application for a settlement permit." — [BAMF](https://www.bamf.de/EN/Infothek/FragenAntworten/BlaueKarteEU/blaue-karte-eu-node.html)*

Comment: Hi @sepehr , what is the deal with anmeldung during this time? say my company allows me to work those 12 months from a non-UE country, do I need to keep my apartment for a whole year without living there? thanks.

Comment: @OmarAguinaga Yup, you should have a registered address in Germany.